# Is there a possibility to visualize intermediate layers in Keras?

Tags: keras, feature-extraction, visualize, densenet

I am using the DenseNet121 CNN in the Keras library and I would like to visualize the features maps when I predict images. I know that is possible with CNN we have made on our own.

Is it the same thing for models available in Keras like DenseNet?